# What is the correct date format for a HtmlUnit input type=date tag?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

The headless HtmlUnit browser seems to support the date type for an input tag:

```
<input type="date" id="mydate">
```

However, I can't figure out which is the correct format for the date that HtmlUnit accepts for this tag. The formates I've tried so far are:

```
dd.mm.yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
yyyy-mm-dd
```

After entering a date in one of the aforementioned formats the input element is always empty.

I interact with HtmlUnit with the Selenium HtmlUnitDriver like this:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("mydate"));
input.sendKeys("2017-10-12");
input.getText(); // returns ""
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code - how do you 'enter' your date and how do you determine that the imput is empty?

Comment: Ok, looks like a bug in HtmlUnit. Please open an issue.

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1923/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the correct format it accepts is `yyyy-MM-dd`

I found the following in the source code in HtmlDateInput file

```
private static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER_ = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found that too, but the value is still not stored.